# `remote_user` is ignored in playbooks and roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have defined the following in my `ansible.cfg`

```
# default user to use for playbooks if user is not specified
# (/usr/bin/ansible will use current user as default)
remote_user = ansible
```

However I have a playbook `bootstrap.yaml` where I connect with `root` rather than `ansible`

```
---
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  become: no
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: root

  vars:
    os_family: "{{ osfamily }}}"

  roles:
  - role: papanito.bootstrap
```

However it seems that `remote_user: root` is ignored as I always get a connection error, because it uses the user `ansible` instead of `root` for the ssh connection

```
fatal: [node001]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false,
"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh:
 ansible@node001: Permission denied (publickey,password).", 
"unreachable": true}
```

The only workaround for this I could find is calling the playbook with `-e ansible_user=root`. But this is not convenient as I want to call multiple playbooks with the `site.yaml`, where the first playbook has to run with `ansible_user` `root`, whereas the others have to run with `ansible`

```
- import_playbook: playbooks/bootstrap.yml
- import_playbook: playbooks/networking.yml
- import_playbook: playbooks/monitoring.yml
```

Any suggestions what I am missing or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: "remote_user: root is ignored"

A: The playbook works as expected

```
- hosts: test_01
  gather_facts: false
  become: no
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - command: whoami
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

gives

```
"result.stdout": "root"
```

But, the variable can be overridden in the inventory. For example with the inventory

```
$ cat hosts
all:
  hosts:
    test_01:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: ssh
    ansible_user: admin
```

the result is

```
"result.stdout": "admin"
```

Double-check the inventory with the command

```
$ ansible-inventory --list
```

---

Notes

- It might be also necessary to  double-check the role `- role: papanito.bootstrap`
- See [Controlling how Ansible behaves: precedence rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#controlling-how-ansible-behaves-precedence-rules)

Comment: You are right, I completely missed the following in my inventory: `ansible_user: ansible`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, where ec2 instance required different username to ssh with. You could try with below example

```
 - import_playbook: playbooks/bootstrap.yml
   vars:
     ansible_ssh_user: root
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

Instead of “remote_user: root”use “remote_user: ansible” and additional “become: yes” ,”become_user: root”,”become_method: sudo or su”

Comment: `become_user` defines the user which is being used for privilege escalation. This is not what I want. For the bootstrapping of the servers I need to connect with root, so no privilege escalation is required